# Why answers appear to my questions out of thin air that I can't accept.

Tags: support, user-accounts

I keep fairly good tabs on my questions for a week or two after I ask them.  Three or four times now it has happened that one of my questions was left unanswered, and then I come back months later and an answer is there, usually within 2 weeks of when I asked it.  Furthermore, I can't accept these answers now.  Is there some way these are appearing?

Comment: Your profile indicates that all the questions you have asked either have accepted answers or no answers at all. Do you have an example for such question with a "ghost answer"?

Comment: It might be related to the fact that you have (at least) two accounts: the one you currently use and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/30666/jeff). If you want those two accounts to be merged, leave a comment here or flag this post and a moderator should take care of this soon.

Comment: Ah yes, I would like these merged into the one I'm using now.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I notified the moderators.

Comment: Based on the comments it seems that this is not a bug, so I've retagged your post from [meta-tag:bug] to [meta-tag:support]. I've also added [meta-tag:user-accounts] - I guess this is an appropriate tag for questions related to merging accounts.

Comment: @Jeff: Check to see if everything seems like it's now in line?

Comment: It seems like everything is working, I'll let you know if something isn't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was resolved in the comments: there were two accounts which are merged now.